# Sending Multiple files using curl http post fropm a bat file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a bat file that contains this:

```
For %%f in (D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\*.xml') do curl --form upload=@D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\%%f --form press=OK http://gateway.companyname.com:5400/companyGateway
```

It is not working. I have multiple xmls that I need to post the bat file is scheduled to run after the xml files are create. all the login info is in the header of the xml file. If I run this from a command prompt it works fine:

```
curl --form upload=@D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\dt.xml --form press=OK http://gateway.Company.com:5400/CompanyGateway
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run `For %%f in (D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\*.xml') do echo %%f` you will see the `%%f` variable already contains full paths like `D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\dt.xml` so simply don't specify the path in `curl` command line:

```
For %%f in (D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\*.xml) do (
  curl --form upload=@%%f --form press=OK http://gateway.companyname.com:5400/companyGateway
)
```

Alternatively you can use [`%%~` prefix](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to extract any part of `drive:\path\name.ext`, e.g. `%%~nxf`.

Comment: Thanks that is not working though I tried running this For %%f in (D:\OrderUploads\company\xmls\*.xml') do echo %%f but nothing echos out.

Comment: @Vic, there's an extra symbol `'` that I've blindly copied from your question, looks like a typo, remove it. As you can see now, running the command by small parts manually is helpful to diagnose the error.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that single tick totally. So now it does echo it and I see the path. Very Nice, but when I run it with the curl statement it doesn't send it. It just flashed a dos window then closes. I put a pause statement in and it isn't executing the curl command. When I manually run the curl statement from the command prompt it connects to the server. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: @Vic, run the batch file from a Command Prompt console (Shift-rightclick the folder where the batch file is located and `Open command window here`)

Comment: thanks that let me run it but it is still not executing the curl command. I went at it a little different way with forfiles, this will execute the command but I cant get the file name to pass to it. It just errors saying couldn't open file "@file" .

FORFILES  /M *.xml /C "cmd /c echo @file
Pause
curl --form upload=@@file --form press=OK http://gateway.company.com:4000/companyGateway

Comment: @Vic, the purpose of running it in the console window is only to check whether *syntax* errors are displayed. What does `curl` say if you add `--verbose` switch to its command line?

Comment: I added that and this is the response
*   Trying 209.9.89.137...
* Connected to gateway.company.com (209.9.89.137) port 4000 (#0)
* couldn't open file "@file"
* Closing connection 0
curl: (26) couldn't open file "@file"

Comment: Thank you!!! I had an errant path in the file in your code I changed it and now it all works!!! Thank you so much!!